# What is the right place to do formating- client or server

Tags: java, javascript, formatting, client-server

While developing for mobile platform which is the right place to do formatting for numbers and dates?

Number and date formatting seems to be easier in Java than Javascript. Is it better to send date as standard format from server and format at client or send nicely formated date from server?

Also, if multiple date formats are supposed to be displayed at few places, is it ok for server to send couple of date strings, each formated in one pattern?

Comment: If you do your Java web development using [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) the question is moot. The entire web app lives on the server, all in pure Java. No need to know or write any JavaScript as Vaadin does that for you.

Comment: I agree the difficulty of coding wouldn't change as both are in Java. But, even in that case we could have logical layers like "Presentation layer" and "Business logic" layer. And then the question will be in which layer is it to be done!

Comment: No, presentation layer versus business layer is a different question. Business logic and data storage should involve minimal or no formatting, as a general rule. Formatting such as deciding on comma versus period for numbers or when to add a dollar sign to a money amount are made in the presentation layer. With conventional web technologies (not Vaadin), that presentation layer bridges across both client (JavaScript) and server (Java, PHP, and such). With Vaadin, both layers exist on the server.

Comment: Ok. I guess you are saying that formating can be done even on serverside, but not to mix with business logic. If the server is REST webservice communicating with Javascript client, would it still be OK to give custom screen-specific formating in the REST service output?

Comment: You can do whatever works for you. But generally a web service provides raw data without formatting so that it might be used in other ways. Assumptions about formatting tend to limit that re-use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your exact situation, but...

Generally, you can always split the solution up to:

**1. Server side**, i.e. create a number of overloaded methods with different time-formats, or even a single smart-method, which detects a format sent (and if unrecognized, throw an exception of unrecognized time format).

**2. Client side**, where you might need (do you?) different times formats to be displayed (e.g. according to users preferences).

*Edit:* To be more specific, as the others already indicated, I'd prefer to choose a server-side for the actual formatting, and then you could do sth like this:

a) get all the formats from the **server** (for instance, as some kind of collection)

b) create a method at the **client** (e.g. javascript, or even some templating system - in this case the analogous array should suffice), which returns the demanded date/time-format

c) display the required format (by using this method or array) in the particular places

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience, it's better to do all the formatting on the server side itself. Consider a scenario, where the client needs to only show the date (not the timestamp), so you would trim the timestamp on server and send it to the client. Down the line, client needs the date and the timestamp both, you would end up modifying your server side code again. Same goes with numbers, amount fields also. Only thing you can ensure from server side is one constant format for any data type. This will ensure smooth contract between client and server.

Comment: "better to do all the formatting on the server side itself" or "constant format for any data type"? If I wanted to send a date to client from server what should be the format? As per the format required in that particular screen?

Comment: No, don't send screen specific date formats. Send one constant format and let the formatting be taken care on each screen. This will not cause any changes on server side if each screen needs a different date format.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I know that javascript can be tricy with number and date formatting. Even though I don't program in Java, I program in PHP. I try to do formatting on the server. Its much more clear and more easy to play around with it.